# Workflow approval on document modification, but not on document upload

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, content-approval, workflow-template

I need to setup a workflow for approval on a document library in SharePoint 2010.  I figured out how to setup approval for everything, including uploading documents, but I don't want that.

I want users to be able to upload documents without approval.  However when they modify a document in the list it needs approval first (i've setup major and minor versioning already) by emailing an approver.  I tried creating a new workflow but the only two templates available are `Disposition Approval` and `Three-state`, both of which I don't think will work for me.

Is this possible?  The site type is a Document Center.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to download SharePoint designer 2010.

Then while in the document library

Go to library tab - > workflow - > create in designer

Fill in name details - > press ok- > check the start workflow on item change check box (bottom right)

Click the edit workflow with text editor

Type start approval process - > change this user to desired user

Publish the workflow and turn off the other approval settings that you configured to begin with